# How to reduce memory allocation with multiple activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, bitmap, out-of-memory

Let's say, I have an app about movies/actors. There is an **activity with movie's (or actor's) details**, in this activity I have **viewpager with 3 fragments**: **A**, **B** and **C**. Each fragment has images which I download from the internet using Picasso and Ion.

I'm using bitmaps, performing transformations, resizing them to the sizes of imageviews so they aren't use much memory. But I don't save them anywhere, I don't need them to be saved.

I have **plenty of images in each fragment** (I use recycler gridview). Fragments B and C has these gridviews with movies or actors, where **click on item opens new details activity** with same fragments and new lists of items. So, I can go really deep opening new activity each time I click on items in the gridviews.

**As the result, I will reach OOM sooner or later, depends on amount of RAM device has. (I was unable to reproduce this on real phone with 2gb memory, but with 512mb app crashes on 5th or 6th opened activity).**

Amount of allocated memory increases on each activity opening. It decreases only then I return to previous ones.

**So the question is:** what should I do to reduce memory use? Should I reuse activities which already exists somehow? I'm not sure how to manage returning back to previous movies then. Yeah, everything is possible, but I don't want make it more complicated or slow.

I have tried to finish previous activities. Or to remove and recycle bitmaps in every imageview in onStop methods. Both ways aren't good cause I have to go back somehow and see data and images. And don't download them again each time.

I hope you can give me an idea, guys. Since I'm new to java and android development, I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Why dont u cache your bitmpas? thats exactly what it is made for!

Comment: Ok, I see now how it works, I guess. You and Gabe Sechan helped me so far to understand where should I look at. Let it be the answer and thank you a lot guys:).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use caching.  Create a fixed size LRUCache and place all images in the cache.  When you need to display an image, check if its in the cache, and if not download from the internet.  With this solution you will never use more than the size of the cache on images.

If you need to, you can consider 2 level (memory/disk) caching.  When you download an image, save it to disk.  Use an LRUCache as above.  When the image is not in the cache, check if its on disk, and if so read from there (and put it in the memory cache).  If its not on disk, fetch it from the internet.

Comment: Yeah, but correct me if I'm wrong. Picasso uses LRU and disk cache by default if needed. As far as I know, it should handle any memory issues without any additional code? Not sure about Ion though, I load most of images with picasso anyway. Or you suggest to do that manually, cache them in onStop method, then load from there in onStart for example? Then why do I need picasso...

Comment: If you're crashing with OOM, either you're not caching them correctly or you're leaking elsewhere (in which case check your hprofs and look for increasing class counts).  The danger in using a library to do your caching for you is that you need to use the library correctly and need to assume the library is written correctly.  Have you read the Picasso codebase to see how it caches and ensure you use it correctly?  If not, blindly assuming it will do the work for you is how people write crappy programs with memory leaks.

Comment: Ok, I see now how it works, I guess. You and AnixPasBesoin helped me so far to understand where should I look at. Let it be the answer and thank you a lot guys:).